# Where is ScrollToCaret in a TextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm unable to find that function. Basically I have a multiline text box and when I perform a search, I highlight the result. But if the result is not within view, I would have to manually scroll down until I find the highlighted result, which beats the purpose of the "Find" functionality.

I don't want to use RichTextBox because I've encountered some performance issues with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlineindexfromcharacterindex.aspx) in combination with [`ScrollToLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.scrolltoline.aspx):

```
var selectionStart = x;
var selectionLength = y;
textBox.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
textBox.ScrollToLine(textBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(textBox.SelectionStart));
```

Comment: Note you should use `textBox.ScrollToLine(textBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(textBox.SelectionStart))`, not `selectionStart`. When you call `Select`, WPF map clip the range if it exceeds the text length, and if you pass something too large to `GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex` it will throw an exception.

Comment: Works like a charm. If you want to see the Selection, you need to focus  the Textbox ```textBox.Focus();```

Comment: Not sure that works if your text goes off screen horizontally. It will go to the line but not the 'column'.

Answer (score -1):

ScrollToLine was not accurate enough for me. My text box had wrapping enabled, so Line Index was not reliable. Instead I used this:

```
textBox.CaretIndex = selectionStart;
textBox.ScrollToEnd();
textBox.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
```

Basically, ScrollToEnd performs a scroll to caret.

Comment: ScrollToEnd does excactly what it says: it scrolls to the end of the content ```Scrolls the view of the editing control to the end of the content.``` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend(v=vs.110).aspx even Microsoft says so!