# How to keep ScrollViewer position?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a textbox as `Log`, the problem is that when I append text, and the user had scroll in the middle, or other position of the scroll, when the new text is appended, the ScrollViewer returns to the top. How can I fix to the user position?

This is my control:

```
<TextBox 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    AcceptsReturn="True" 
    Height="240" 
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    x:Name="txtLog"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    />
```

Here's how I append the text:

```
txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
txtLog.AppendText(text);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793548/how-to-prevent-textbox-auto-scrolls-when-append-text

Comment: @Rowbear too much code for block a ScrollViewer

Comment: the bounty receiving answer only has a few lines of code that controls the scroll location :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TextBox.TextChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

[TextBox.VerticalOffset Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.verticaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx)

I think you can use both of the above Members of the TextBox class to achieve your goal.

https: //msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.extentheight(v=vs.110).aspx 
(need more rep to post 3 links, pff... lol)

With the (link above) ExtentHeight you could also check for max scroll position.

Unfortunally I do not know, whether you need to store the ScrollPosition before making changes or if the Event TextChanged is called during changing of the Text (meaning having the Text original in the object inside the EventHandler and after leaving the new Text).

Cheers

Comment: BTW, it might even be simpler when overriding the OnTextInput Handler of the TextInput Event (of the SCROLLVIEWER). But you would have to test that yourself, sorry. Other possible Events to get changes on the control are SourceUpdated and TargetUpdated, but I guess for this task, those latter Events are overkills.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is...awkward. You're essentially working with one giant textbox, which is inefficient for a variety of reasons. I'd change your implementation to a ListView or VirutulaizingStackPanel you add strings to. This has the advantages of having the behavior you're looking for by default and being more memory efficient if you use virtualization.

If you absolutely can't do that, You can use the IScrollProvider interface and associated classes in the UIAtuomationProvider and UIAutomationTypes assemblies to manually set the scroll position every time you add text.