# Disable Text Scrolling when text is longer than the TextBox Width

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a customTextBox1 on a Form.
customTextbox1 **multiline is false** and TextAlign is set to center.MaxLength is 23. And the customTextBox1 width is 92.customTextBox1 Font is set to  "ＭＳ ゴシック", 12F.
When I type "12345678901234567890123" in the TextBox, the text is scrolling to the last character.Also,when I click on the text , the text is highlighted blue and I can drag to the left and right of the text.

**.NetFramework 3.5**

What I want is 2 things:

1)when the text is longer than TextBox width, I don't want to scroll to the last character.I want to stop scrolling at the right margin of the TextBox.
for example,
when I type "1234567890123456", I want to show "12345678901"and the rest of the overflow text should not be shown.

2)when I Click and Drag the text,   I want to show "12345678901" only
And want to get rid of the blue highlighted selection too.

1)overflow text is showing
[image: overflow text is showing]

2)i can click and drag to the end of the text and beginning of the text
[image: i can click and drag to the end of the text and beginning of the text And I want to prevent this]

here is my code

CustomTextBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DisabledTextSelectForm
{
    public partial class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public override bool AutoSize
        {
            get { return base.AutoSize; }
            set { base.AutoSize = value; }
        }

        public CustomTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DisabledTextSelectForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            customTextBox1.AutoSize = true;
            customTextBox1.Size = new Size(92,21);
            customTextBox1.Multiline = false;
            customTextBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            customTextBox1.MaxLength = 23;
            customTextBox1.Font = new Font("ＭＳ ゴシック", 12F);


        }
    }
}
```

**Update1 :**

I want to do this strange behavior of textBox because I am making a exact  replica of an application written in other language which is not supported anymore. So we have to write it in C#. Both application will run on windows.
In the old application, there is a textBox in which user can type in ID numbers.

1)That textBox does not show overflow text.
If I type ("12345678901234567890123") ,it only show "12345678901" but if I click backspace [13]times, the text begins "1234567890". so I know the overflow text are there just not showing.

2)I can't click and drag the text right and left as in C# textBox.

I have manage to replicate No.1 behavior though.
Here is my code

CustomTextBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DisabledTextSelectForm
{
    public partial class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public override bool AutoSize
        {
            get { return base.AutoSize; }
            set { base.AutoSize = value; }
        }

        public bool DisabledScrolling { get; set; }

        int caretPos = 0;

        public CustomTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            var isDigit = char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
            var isBackSpace = e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back;

            var diffWidth = 0;

            if (Text.Length >= 2)
            {
                var firstChar = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text[0].ToString(), Font);
                var secondChar = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text.Substring(0, 2).ToString(), Font);

                diffWidth = secondChar.Width - firstChar.Width;

                caretPos = Width / diffWidth;

            }

            if (caretPos != 0 && Text.Length >= caretPos  && DisabledScrolling)
            {
                
                if (isDigit)
                {
                    Text = Text.Length < MaxLength ? Text + e.KeyChar.ToString() : Text;
                }
                else if (isBackSpace)
                {
                    Text = Text.Substring(0,Text.Length - 1);
                }

                ScrollTo(caretPos - 1);
                e.Handled = true;

            }


            base.OnKeyPress(e);
        }

        private void ScrollTo(int scrollPosition)
        {
            if (Text.Length >= scrollPosition)
            {
                Select(scrollPosition, 0);
                ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DisabledTextSelectForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            customTextBox1.DisabledScrolling = true;
            customTextBox1.AutoSize = true;
            customTextBox1.Size = new Size(92,21);
            customTextBox1.Multiline = false;
            customTextBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            customTextBox1.MaxLength = 23;
            customTextBox1.Font = new Font("ＭＳ ゴシック", 12F);


        }
    }
}
```

I know how to disable clicking and draging of Text in TextBox.

[image: Do not show overflow text]
[image: want to disable selecting of Text]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent TextBox auto scrolls when append text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793548/how-to-prevent-textbox-auto-scrolls-when-append-text)

Comment: @OlivierRogierThank you for answering.But I ask for A single Line TextBox without any scroll bar.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can achieve this by using API and window messages but DON'T do it! You would change the expected behavior of textbox. What is the use-case?

Comment: @Steeeve I know it is not good for C# textbox but I have to do it. I am making a exact replica of an application written in other language which is not supported anymore. So we have to write it in C#. Both application will run on windows.

Comment: Thus you should be able to create your own [custom text box control](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+create+custom+textbox).

Comment: I am creating customTextBox but i dont know how to disable selection of text in a single-line textbox.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Timer then set it Enable with 10 ms interval and in Tick event of your Timer put this code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

2. In MouseMove event of your TextBox put this code:

```
    private void textBox1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

3. In KeyDown event of your TextBox put this code:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    }
```

4. Add this code in initialize block

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.HideSelection = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. this looks promising but it flickers when I drag right and left of the text .

Comment: your welcome. yes that is right. do you need to drag?